# Can I initialize a C# attribute with an array or other variable number of arguments?

Tags: c#, attributes

Is it possible to create an attribute that can be initialized with a variable number of arguments?

For example:

```
[MyCustomAttribute(new int[3,4,5])]  // this doesn't work
public MyClass ...
```

Comment: You just have your syntax for the array wrong. It should be "new int [] { 3,4,5 }".

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Attributes will take an array. Though if you control the attribute, you can also use `params` instead (which is nicer to consumers, IMO):

```
class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute {
    public int[] Values { get; set; }

    public MyCustomAttribute(params int[] values) {
       this.Values = values;
    }
}

[MyCustomAttribute(3, 4, 5)]
class MyClass { }
```

Your syntax for array creation just happens to be off:

```
class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute {
    public int[] Values { get; set; }

    public MyCustomAttribute(int[] values) {
        this.Values = values;
    }
}

[MyCustomAttribute(new int[] { 3, 4, 5 })]
class MyClass { }
```

Comment: Using `params` is a great tip. Creates a user-friendly attribute.

Answer (score 41):

You can do it, but it isn't CLS compliant:

```
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]

class Foo : Attribute
{
    public Foo(string[] vals) { }
}
[Foo(new string[] {"abc","def"})]
static void Bar() {}
```

Shows:

```
Warning 1   Arrays as attribute arguments is not CLS-compliant
```

For regular reflection usage, it may be preferable to have multiple attributes, i.e.

```
[Foo("abc"), Foo("def")]
```

However, this won't work with `TypeDescriptor`/`PropertyDescriptor`, where only a single instance of any attribute is supported (either the first or last wins, I can't recall which).

Comment: note: multiple attributes requires a AttributeUsage attribute on your attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553540/how-to-create-duplicate-allowed-attribute

Answer (score 28):

Try declaring the constructor like this:

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyCustomAttribute(params int[] t)
    {
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

`[MyCustomAttribute(3, 4, 5)]`

Answer (score 14):

That should be okay. From the spec, section 17.2:

An expression E is an *attribute-argument-expression* if all of the following statements are true:

- The type of E is an attribute parameter type (§17.1.3).
- At compile-time, the value of E can be resolved to one of the following:

  - A constant value.
  - A System.Type object.
  - A one-dimensional array of *attribute-argument-expressions*.

Here's an example:

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class SampleAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SampleAttribute(int[] foo)
    {
    }
}

[Sample(new int[]{1, 3, 5})]
class Test
{
}
```

Comment: Watch out for CLS compliance, though

Answer (score 7):

Yes, but you need to initialize the array that you are passing in. Here is an example from a row test in our unit tests that tests a variable number of command line options;

```
[Row( new[] { "-l", "/port:13102", "-lfsw" } )]
public void MyTest( string[] args ) { //... }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that. Another example could be:

```
class MyAttribute: Attribute
{
    public MyAttribute(params object[] args)
    {
    }
}

[MyAttribute("hello", 2, 3.14f)]
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To piggy back on Marc Gravell's answer, yes you can define an attribute with array parameters but applying an attribute with an array parameter is not CLS-compliant. However just defining an attribute with an array property is perfectly CLS-compliant.

What made me realize this was that Json.NET, a CLS-compliant library, has an attribute class JsonPropertyAttribute with a property named ItemConverterParameters that's an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I use maybe a bit stupid workaround using this trick:

```
public class CLParam : Attribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Command line parameter
    /// </summary>
    public string Names { get; set; }
}
```

and then splitting the Names into string[]:

```
var names = loadAtt.Names.Split(',');
```

I allows me to use attribute like this:

```
class CLContext
{
    [CLParam(Names = "selectscene,ss")]
    public List<string> SelectScene { get; set; }
```

But of course for ints you would need to parse texts, so maybe a bit slow...