# How to create duplicate allowed attributes

Tags: c#, attributes

I'm using a custom attribute inherited from an attribute class. I'm using it like this:

```
[MyCustomAttribute("CONTROL")]
[MyCustomAttribute("ALT")]
[MyCustomAttribute("SHIFT")]
[MyCustomAttribute("D")]
public void setColor()
{

}
```

But the "Duplicate 'MyCustomAttribute' attribute" error is shown.
How can I create a duplicate allowed attribute?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Stick an `AttributeUsage` attribute onto your Attribute class (yep, that's mouthful) and set `AllowMultiple` to `true`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class MyCustomAttribute: Attribute
```

Comment: Just curious - why a "sealed" class?

Comment: Microsoft recommends sealing attribute classes whenever possible: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ab31zeh.aspx

Comment: Why sealed? In short: Makes attribute lookup faster and has no other impact.

Comment: Except that it stops anyone else from reusing your code. Worth noting that validation attributes in DataAnnotations are _not_ sealed, which is extremely useful as it make it possible to create specializations of them.

Comment: @Neutrino sealed should be used whenever you don't expect  or dint't design your classes to be inherited. Plus, when the inheritance may become the source of bugs ex: Thread-safe implementations.

Answer (score 20):

AttributeUsageAttribute ;-p

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{}
```

Note, however, that if you are using ComponentModel (`TypeDescriptor`), it only supports one attribute instance (per attribute type) per member; raw reflection supports any number...

Answer (score 14):

[Anton's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553540/how-to-create-duplicate-allowed-attribute/553551#553551) is correct, but there is [another gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848669/allowmultiple-does-not-work-with-property-attributes/1365669#1365669).

In short, unless your custom attribute overrides TypeId, then accessing it through `PropertyDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes()` will only return a single instance of your attribute.

Comment: But it works via: 
var customAtt = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes<MyCustomAttribute>();

Answer (score 14):

By default, `Attribute`s are limited to being applied only once to a single field/property/etc. You can see this from the [definition of the `Attribute` class on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute(v=vs.110).aspx#Syntax):

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(..., AllowMultiple = false)]
public abstract class Attribute : _Attribute
```

Therefore, as others have noted, all subclasses are limited in the same way, and should you require multiple instances of the same attribute, you need to explicitly set `AllowMultiple` to `true`:

```
[AttributeUsage(..., AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
```

On attributes that allow multiple usages, [you should also override the `TypeId` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w3a7b50(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) to ensure that properties such as [`PropertyDescriptor.Attributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.memberdescriptor.attributes(v=vs.110).aspx)  work as expected. The easiest way to do this is to implement that property to return the attribute instance itself:

```
[AttributeUsage(..., AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public override object TypeId
    {
        get
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

(Posting this answer not because the others are wrong, but because this is a more comprehensive/canonical answer.)

Answer (score 4):

After you add the AttributeUsage, make sure you add this property to your Attribute class

```
public override object TypeId
{
  get
  {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, think about redesigning your attribute to allow for a sequence.

```
[MyCustomAttribute(Sequence="CONTROL,ALT,SHIFT,D")]
```

or

```
[MyCustomAttribute("CONTROL-ALT-SHIFT-D")]
```

then parse the values to configure your attribute.

For an example of this check out the AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET MVC source code at [www.codeplex.com/aspnet](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet).

Comment: It is even possible to have the `MyCustomAttribute` constructor take an *array* of strings, a `string[]`, with or without the `params` modifier. Then it could be applied with the syntax `[MyCustom("CONTROL", "ALT", "SHIFT", "D")]` (with `params`).