# AllowMultiple does not work with Property Attributes?

Tags: attributes, custom-attributes

I'm tying to collect all Custom Attributes placed over a Property. There are more than one Attributes of the same type assigned to the Property, but when collecting them , the resulting collection only contains the first Attribute of the specific type:

The Attribute class

```
[AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property,
               AllowMultiple = true)]

public class ConditionAttribute : Attribute{...}
```

Usage:

```
[ConditionAttribute("Test1")]
[ConditionAttribute("Test2")]
[ConditionAttribute("Test3")]
public Color BackColor{get; set;}
```

Now when looping through all Props of the object 'value' whose class contains the Prop "BackColor":

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value))
{
  foreach (Attribute attribute in property.Attributes)
  {   ... }
   ....
}
```

the  collection **property.Attributes** only contains ONE Attribute of type "ConditionAttribute" : The one with "Test1". The others are ignored;-(

So does AllowMultiple not work for Property Attributes ?

Thanks in advance

henrik

Answer (score 25):

According to [a post on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/e6bb4146-eb1a-4c1b-a5b1-f3528d8a7864), this is by design as part of the PropertyDescriptor class.

However, you can actually solve the problem by overriding TypeId in your custom attribute (Thanks to [Ivan from Mindscape](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/forums/Thread.aspx?ThreadID=2323) for pointing this out):

```
public override object TypeId
{
  get
  {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: I encountered a similar issue while using a custom ValidationAttribute in MVC; this solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does work.  Not sure why it does not work via PropertyDescriptors.

You can always do: `Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(methodInfo, typeof(ConditionAttribute))`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to tweak this,

[ConditionAttribute("Test1,Test2,Test3")]
public Color BackColor{get; set;}

and in your validation code,

Dim lstProperties() As String = _ChkColors.Split(",")
For each strProp as string in lstPropertyes
  ' your validation
  ' return
Next