# At least one of inputs are required

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, entity-framework

How can I be sure that at least one of `FatherName` or `AncestorName` Is filled?

- How can I manage that in `MyEntity.cs` since I shouldn't use `[Required]` annotation for both of them?

  ```
  [Required]
  public string FatherName { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string AncestorName { get; set; }
  ```
- How can I manage it in UI?

Now I have a class for required inputs in UI. On each `'.required-input'` elements `change`, jQuery will check the elements with `'.required-input'` class are filled or not, and then the submit button will be enabled/disabled.

Also all required elements have a `*` sign.

```
$('#create').prop("disabled", true);
$(document).on('change', '.required-input', function() {
    var requiredInputsAreFilled = true;
    $('.required-input').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            requiredInputsAreFilled = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (requiredInputsAreFilled) {
        $('#create').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $('#create').prop("disabled", true);
    }
}).change();
```

Comment: But even if you manage to do that validation on client side, your server side will fail because you have required on both of them.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, OK, exactly I want to know how can I manage it in server-side, too. Is there any solution in entity-framework?

Comment: You need `custom validator` to do it.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712511/data-annotations-for-validation-at-least-one-required-field.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data Annotations for validation, at least one required field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712511/data-annotations-for-validation-at-least-one-required-field)