# Data Annotations - MVC

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I have an MVC form in which there are two fields - One for Mobile number and another for Landline Number.
Either of the fields should have values.
Need to perform validation using data annotation.
Using required property both will be mandatory.
So just want to make only one mandatory( user can put both the numbers, atleast one is inputted)

Comment: Possible Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712511/data-annotations-for-validation-at-least-one-required-field

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data Annotations for validation, at least one required field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712511/data-annotations-for-validation-at-least-one-required-field)

Comment: use IValidatableObject to have it configured inside viewmodel class