# Passing List<Enum> parameters into custom action filter in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

how I can parse List into me custom action filter (like input parameters) ?

```
public class CustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public List<MyEnumType> InputParameter { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {         
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}

[CustomFilter(InputParameter = new List<MyEnumType>() { MyEnumType.Type } )]
public SomeActionInController()
{
}
```

I got errror Error

```
'InputParameter' is not a valid named attribute argument because it is not a valid attribute parameter type
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Action filter parameters are properties of the action filter:

```
[CustomFilter(InputParameter=10)]
public SomeActionInController()
{
}

public class CustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public int InputParameter { get; set; }

  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    // access this.InputParameter

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
  }
}
```

Attribute parameter types are limited to the types described here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664615%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

You can pass a collection via the attributes constructor as described here - [Can I initialize a C# attribute with an array or other variable number of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270187/can-i-initialize-a-c-attribute-with-an-array-or-other-variable-number-of-argumen)

Comment: this work fine, but if I parse List<Enum> then I got error, pls check edited post