# ASP.NET MVC 3 - How to execute code after leaving a View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm in some trouble here. I have a view in which a company can thumbs up or down users of our site. The users are listed in a table and a column has the little hand images for the company to vote for or against the user. I had programmed an ActionLink there, however, I don't want a postback to happen every time a company vote on a user.

I decided to fill a list with the user IDs the company votes on and then, when leaving the page, a filter would intercept the request, get the list and process the votes. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676407/passing-listenum-parameters-into-custom-action-filter-in-asp-net-mvc3) I was taught how to initialize Filter parameters when calling the Action, but as you can see, I need a way for the Filter to get the Lists when the user exits the View, not in an Action.

I wouldn't want to use code-behind because, paired with MVC, it is not a best practice, but postbacks are not an option either.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public ActionResult ListUsers()
{
    // Create a List with user models and send it to a View,
    // which generates a WebGrid

    return View(userList);
}

public class PromoteUsersFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public int[] UsersToPromote { get; set; }
    public int[] UsersToScrewWith { get; set; }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //insert promoting logic here
    }
}
```

I believe there is a simple way of doing it, since most websites have this funcionality. Can anyone guide me with this?

Comment: "When leaving the page" is not an event you can handle on the server. "When leaving the page" could be the browser closing and you will get nothing back.  Use AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely go for the AJAX solution:

It could look like this in your view:

```
<div>
    <span class="cssUpvote" id="upvote"><span>
    <span class="cssDownvote" id="downvote"></span>
</div>
```

with some Jquery

```
<script>
   $(document).on('click', 'upvote', function (event) {

       $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '/Votes/Upvote',
             data: { id: companyId }
       });
   });

   $(document).on('click', 'downvote', function (event) {

       $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '/Votes/Downvote',
             data: { id: companyId }
       });
   });
</script>
```

And then your actions on the Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upvote(int id)
{
    //Do something with the (company)id
    return Json();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Downvote(int id)
{
    //Do something with the (company)id
    return Json();
}
```

Comment: I was doing some maintenance in my StackOverflow account and found out that I hadn't chosen a proper answer for this question back then, so I decided to do it now, since this is the way I've been handling these kinds of situations ever since. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use AJAX that calls into your controller methods? If you set up your json properly, it will still be deserialized into an object, too.

This is OK even in the MVC mindset as far as I know. If you need to persist your data, but not update the entire page it is the only way that I know. You can even swap out entire partial views using AJAX.

I think the common misconception here is that the View portion (of MVC) is not just one page, but actually made up of a number of views smashed into the one page. So, updating one of those views separately does not really break the pattern.