# Attribute error: An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Tags: c#, .net

I want to pass some list of enums to my Attribute property. But it's pretty you can pass List to Attribute's property. So I tried converting it to string representation and tried to do something like this:

```
[MyAtt(Someproperty = 
            Enums.SecurityRight.A.ToString() + "&" + (Enums.SecurityRight.B.ToString() ))]
```

However, this gives the error: "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type"

I understand you can only pass constants. But how do I get away with this? Any tricks?

Thanks.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270187/can-i-initialize-a-c-attribute-with-an-array-or-other-variable-number-of-argumen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please pardon me if my C# coding is off.  I use VB.

You can use `const` values.

```
namespace Enums {
    static class SecurityRight {
        const String A = "A";
        const String B = "B";
    }
}

[MyAtt(StringProperty = Enums.SecurityRight.A + "&" + Enums.SecurityRight.B)]
```

You can use an `enum` if the attribute accepts the same data type as an enum.

```
namespace Enums {
    [Flags()]
    enum int SecurityRight {
        A = 1;
        B = 2;
    }
}

[MyAtt(IntegerProperty = Enums.SecurityRight.A | Enums.SecurityRight.B)]
```

**EDIT:** Changed `IntegerProperty` above to receive multiple values.

Attributes are set at compile time, not at runtime.  By using `ToString`, you are invoking code that is used in runtime.  You must use a constant value.

Comment: Nice but not exactly what I was looking for. I was looking for your 2nd approach where enum is used. I want to send in 2 enum in 1 property. But you only sent one. [MyAtt(IntegerProperty = Enums.SecurityRight.A)]

Comment: how does this allow passing of a list of values to the attribute?

Comment: @Jaggu, If you want to send them as a String, you'll have to type them as strings or find some other way that doesn't involve a function call.  If you want to sent the combined value as a number, you can use `Enum.A | Enum.B`.

Comment: @AdamRalph, I didn't understand what was meant by list in this context until now.  The first block of code works for a list provided the attribute is expecting that format.

Comment: By List I meant I have a `List<Enums> enums;` in my attribute and I can pass in that from consumer. But that is not possible. The link that Adam provided solved the issue where one can pass in array using params.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood the question.