# How to put an array of enum in a authorize attribute?

Tags: c#, enums, authorization

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
   [CustomAuthorize(Permissions = new[] { /*These are Enums */Permissions.CanChangeProducts.ToString(), Permissions.CanChangeNames.ToString()})]
    public ActionResult MyMethod()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

It gives the error:

Error   5   An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type [...]

I've managed to put Resource string into validationattibutes, but I could'n manage to put this enum (string) array into a authorize attribute... How can I do that? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What Type is permissions? All the error is saying is it's not String[]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
enum.Value | enum.Value | enum.Value
```

What about `flags`?

Like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Constructor | AttributeTargets.Enum)]
```

**Edit:** By the way, there is very interesting answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/270231/2524304

Comment: Ok, I'm putting these enums inside a string[] variable inside a custom authorization class that inherits the authorizeAttribute... How can I use the flag? Because the number of parameters that the 'Permission' array receives variates

Comment: Edited, added link to possible answer

Comment: Okay! I went on the link you send and I got an answer... I just had to put the enum array itself inside the class and it worked! haha thanks... I'm still gonna try to use flags for this!